# multithreading of structure using mfc

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

have a mfc remote desktop application,structure is written in proxyserver .

How can i convert this structure into multithreading ?

```
struct sAccept
{
    CTCPSocket * m_pAccept;
    CString m_csAlias;
    CString m_csIp;
    BOOL m_bRDV;
    bool operator < (const sAccept & rhs) const {return *m_pAccept < *(rhs.m_pAccept);}
    std::set<CString> m_Viewers;

};
```

Comment: Structures can't be multi-threaded, but programs can be. You need to give more details about your program, what you are doing and what you want to accomplish, and why you think multi-threading might be good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,can't i put the structure pointer in threads ?my application desktop proxy server is single threaded i want to make it multithreaded.when traffic more during concurrent data transfer application is going to not responding state.to avoid exe hanging want to make it multithreaded.if i put this structure pointer in thread will it helpful instead  socket class

Comment: Multithreading requires executing functions in a secondary thread. Data and pointers do not make anything multithreaded.

Comment: // Send the packet to all connected clients
void Crp::SendToAllConnectedClients(CPacket & Packet)
{ std::vector<CString> vAliases;
 std::set<sAccept>::iterator itAccept = m_setAccept.begin();
 for (;itAccept != m_setAccept.end();++itAccept)
 {  
  // Locate the server
  if (!itAccept->m_bRDV && Packet.m_csServer == itAccept->m_csAlias)
  {
    // Locate the viewers of this server
   std::set<CString>::iterator itView = itAccept->m_Viewers.begin();
   for (;itView != itAccept->m_Viewers.end();++itView)
   {

Comment: // Locate each viewers connection and send the update
    CString csViewer = *itView;
    for (std::set<sAccept>::iterator itAccept2 = m_setAccept.begin();itAccept2 != m_setAccept.end();++itAccept2) {
     if (itAccept2->m_bRDV && itAccept2->m_csAlias == csViewer)     {
                       // This really needs to be in its own thread...
      CTCPSocket & Alias = *(itAccept2->m_pAccept);
      Alias << Packet;                      

     }    }
   }
   break;
  }
  
 }
}want to make this funcion multi threaded and this function uses the SAccept structure.

Comment: the above function has to be multi threaded.Locate viewers connection should be in different thread.need help

Comment: @user3347271 don't post additional code here in the comments. Instead, update your question to reflect updates or clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MFC socket classes this article shows how to transfer a socket to another thread with the Detach and Attach member functions.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140527

Comment: Thanks,but i want put above method in multithread.code is shared.i tried but its not working as expected.